# Epsilon proof for sequence $\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})^3 = 64$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So I have to prove that $\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})^3 = 64$ using the formal definition of a limit. Here is what I've done so far

> $\forall \space\epsilon > 0  \space \exists \space N \in \mathbb{N} 
> \space | \space n > N \implies |a_n - L| < \epsilon$
>
> Let N = $(\frac{61}{\epsilon})^\frac{1}{2}$
>
> n > N
>
> n > $(\frac{61}{\epsilon})^\frac{1}{2}$
>
> $n^2 > (\frac{61}{\epsilon})$
>
> $\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{61}{\epsilon}$
>
> $\frac{61}{n^2} < \epsilon$
>
> $\frac{48}{n^2} +\frac{12}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^6} < \frac{48}{n^2} +\frac{12}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{61}{n^2} < \epsilon$
>
> $\frac{48}{n^2} +\frac{12}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^6} +64 < \epsilon + 64$
>
> $(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})^\frac{1}{3} < \epsilon + 64$
>
> $(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})^\frac{1}{3} - 64 < \epsilon$

I know im close, but where do I go from here? Or is this a valid proof?. I'm confused on what my end goal is.

Comment: Please distinguish when you write a statement whether that is a definition, somthing you concluded to be true, a statement that needs to be proven or what.  As it stands your proof is incomprehensible.  However if you *had* indicated which were assigned values,which we observed truths, and which were statements to be proven, then your proof would be completed and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate what the statements are supposed to respresent and why they are stated:

The definition of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n = L$ is

> ∀ ϵ>0 ∃ N∈N | n>N⟹|an−L|<ϵ

So we need to should that for any $\epsilon > 0 \exists N\in \mathbb N| n > N \implies |(4+\frac 1{n^2})^3 - 64| < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

> Let $N = (\frac {61}ϵ)^{\frac 12}$
>
> n > N

What's $n$.  You need to state:

> ***If*** $n > N$

then

> $n > (\frac{61}ϵ)^{\frac 12}$
>
> $n^2>\frac {61}{\epsilon}$
>
> $\frac 1{n^2} < \frac {61}ϵ$

Oops.  That's not true.  What you have is $\frac 1{n^2} < \frac {\epsilon}{61}$

> $\frac{61}{n^2}<ϵ$

Okay, I guess two wrongs *do* make a right, as that is no correct again.

> A: $\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^4}+\frac 1{n^6}<\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^2}+\frac 1{n^2}=\frac {61}{n^2}<ϵ$
>
> $\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^4}+\frac 1{n^6}+64<\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^2}+\frac 1{n^2}=\frac {61}{n^2}<ϵ+64$
>
> $(4+\frac 1{n^2})^{\frac 13}<ϵ+64$

Um... that's not true. $\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^4}+\frac 1{n^6}+64 \ne (4+\frac 1{n^2})^{\frac 13}$

$\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^4}+\frac 1{n^6}+64 = (4+\frac 1{n^2})^{3}$

So why did you write it to the $\frac 13$ power.

....

Now you are basically done.

Then $(4 + \frac 1{n^2})^3 < \epsilon + 64$

$(4+\frac 1{n^2})^3 - 64 < \epsilon$

We need to prove $(4+\frac 1{n^2})^3 - 64 > 0$.

$n > 0$ so $\frac 1n > 0$ so $\frac 1{n^2} > 0$ so $4 + \frac 1{n^2} > 4$ so $(4+\frac 1{n^2})^2> 4^3 = 64$ so $(4+\frac 1{n^2})^3 - 64 > 0$.

So $0 < (4+\frac 1{n^2})^3 - 64 = |(4+\frac 1{n^2})^3 - 64| < \epsilon$.

We are done.

Comment: why do we have to prove that $(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})^3 - 64 > 0$?

Comment: Because if it is less than zero we will not know that its absolute value is less than epsilon.  If it is positive than it is equal to its absolute value and it is less than epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is okay.  But I would write it up nearly back to front from how you have it.

Quote the definition, that is great.

then:

$(4-\frac {1}{n^2})^3 - 64 = \frac {48}{n^2} + \frac {12}{n^4} + \frac 1{n^6}$

if $n>1$

$0<\frac {48}{n^2} + \frac {12}{n^4} + \frac 1{n^6} < \frac {61}{n^2} < \epsilon$

Let $N = \max (1, \sqrt \frac {61}{\epsilon})$

$n>N \implies |(4-\frac 1{n^2})^3 - 64| < \frac {61}{n^2} < \epsilon$

Comment: But I can't start with the $|(4 - \frac{1}{n^2})^3 - 64| < \epsilon$ because thats what I'm trying to prove no? And Im working with sequences here, so $n > 1$ is assumed.

Comment: You can start there.  What you need to show is that there exists and $N$ such that $n>N$ will always make your proposition true.  So, you can assume that it is true and then find the $N$ that properly binds it.  However, if that makes you feel uncomfortable, I have made a slight change that you will like a little better.

Comment: @DougM I think you should put $[\sqrt{\frac{61}{\epsilon}}]$ as $N$ is a natural number

Comment: Nothing says that $N \in \mathbb N$ just that $n\in \mathbb N$

Comment: Perhaps another way of putting this is: We want to find an $n$ so that $|(4+\frac 1{n^2})^3-64 |< \epsilon$.  This will happen whenever $\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^2}+ \frac 1{n^6}<\epsilon$.  That will happen whenever $\frac{61}{n^2} < \epsilon$ which will occur whenever $n > \sqrt\frac {61}{\epsilon}$.  So for $\epsilon$ there exists an $N=\sqrt{\frac{61}{\epsilon}}$ so that $n>N \implies$ what we want.  There is *nothing* in there where you assume what you want to prove.  You *solve* for what can give you what you want to prove and *in solving* prove your result.